# What is the output of GridSearchCV(): a trained classifier or a series of classifiers with different hyperparameters?

Tags: python

I am learning Nested Cross Validation on sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

The example sklearn team gave:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, KFold
import numpy as np

# Number of random trials
NUM_TRIALS = 30

# Load the dataset
iris = load_iris()
X_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target

# Set up possible values of parameters to optimize over
p_grid = {"C": [1, 10, 100], "gamma": [0.01, 0.1]}

# We will use a Support Vector Classifier with "rbf" kernel
svm = SVC(kernel="rbf")

# Arrays to store scores
non_nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)
nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)

# Loop for each trial
for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):

    # Choose cross-validation techniques for the inner and outer loops,
    # independently of the dataset.
    # E.g "GroupKFold", "LeaveOneOut", "LeaveOneGroupOut", etc.
    inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=outer_cv)
    clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
    non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_

    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
    nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

In this part:

```
 # Nested CV with parameter optimization
 clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
 nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
 nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

I don't quite understand that:
whether `clf` in `cross_val_score` is a series of classifiers (each with a set of hypermeters) to be trained with X_iris and y_iris,
or `clf` in `cross_val_score` is a already trained classifier, with the best parameters, and just need to be cross validated with X_iris and y_iris.

Moreover, in this part:

```
# Choose cross-validation techniques for the inner and outer loops,
# independently of the dataset.
# E.g "GroupKFold", "LeaveOneOut", "LeaveOneGroupOut", etc.
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
```

What does KFold return?
A indexes of k-folded split, which are used to split the data later?

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question:

Yes, K-Folds cross-validator means that it "Provides train/test indices to split data in train/test sets."

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).